# How to call a function 10 seconds after calling another function?

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout, innerhtml

I have two functions, functionOne() and functionTwo().

How can I go about calling functionTwo() 10 seconds after functionOne() ends/is called?

I'd like functionOne to occur after a button is clicked, and then functionTwo 10 seconds after functionOne ends (without the need to click a button again/have the user do anything!)!

See below for my code!

```
<p id="paragraphChange">"Hello World"</p>
<button type="button" id="clickToChangeText" onClick="functionOne()">Click!</button>    

<script>
    
    functionOne() {
        document.getElementById("paragraphChange").innerHTML = "Bye World";
    }

    functionTwo() {
        document.getElementById("paragraphChange").innerHTML = "Jokes I'm still here";
    }
    
</script>
```

I tried to use setTimeout, but the problem is that I don't think there is an 'onend' event I can use for the first function. Eg:

setTimeout(functionOne.onend, 10,000);

Comment: It feels like you are confused about how [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) works. You pass the action which should happen after a timeout, not what starts happening after something finishes. That would be *more of a* [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Most importantly you have to *declare* your functions properly using the `function` keyword: `function functionOne`, `function functionTwo`.
2. Here's [the documentation for `setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout): *"The global setTimeout() method sets a timer which executes *a function*... once the timer expires."* So you pass in the function that you want to execute once the timer has completed.

And here are some more methods of approaching the problem.

3. Cache your paragraph element along with the button up front so you're making the code as DRY as possible.
4. Move the inline JS to the script, and use [`addEventListner`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the para element
5. Use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of `innerHTML` because you're not adding HTML

```js
// Cache the elements
const para = document.querySelector('#paragraphChange');
const button = document.querySelector('#clickToChangeText');

// Add a listener to the button
button.addEventListener('click', functionOne, false);

// Set the text content of the para element
// and then call the second function with a time out
function functionOne() {
  para.textContent = 'Bye World';
  setTimeout(functionTwo, 5000);
}

// Update the para with new text
function functionTwo() {
  para.textContent = 'Jokes I\'m still here';
}
```

```html
<p id="paragraphChange">"Hello World"</p>
<button type="button" id="clickToChangeText">Click!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code calls `functionOne` onClick and calls `functionTwo` 10 seconds later.

```
<p id="paragraphChange">"Hello World"</p>
<button type="button" id="clickToChangeText" onClick="functionOne()">Click!</button>        
   
<script>
    
    function functionOne() {
        document.getElementById("paragraphChange").innerHTML = "Bye World";
        setTimeout(() => functionTwo(), 10000);
    }
    
    function functionTwo() {
        document.getElementById("paragraphChange").innerHTML = "Jokes I'm still here";
    }   
</script>
```

Comment: Neither of those are functions because they haven't been declared with the `function` keyword.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there anything called `onend` in JavaScript you have to use `setTimeout(functionTwo, 10000)` at the end of `functionOne()` like this:

```
function functionTwo() {
    //code to be execute
}

function functionOne(){
    //code to be execute
    
    //End of function
    setTimeout(functionTwo, 10000);
}
```

Comment: Neither of those are functions because they haven't been declared with the `function` keyword.

Comment: Forgot to mention function keyword edited as per pointed out by @Andy

Comment: I have a question @vinas - what if my function ends by an if statement? Like, if it's a countdown function and then if (minutes and seconds == "0"), then inside that there's some code that aborts/ends the function (i'm using speech recognition). Where could I put the setTimeout function?

Answer (score -1):

Define functionTow() first.

```
function functionTwo() {
    //code to be execute
}
```

The call functionTwo in functionOne's body using setTimeout.

```
function functionOne(){
    //code to be execute
    
    //End of function
    setTimeout(functionTwo, 10000);
}
```

Comment: The position of where the function is defined does not change anything

Comment: **Define functionTow() first.** You are not defining any `function`.

Comment: I have a question @Basharat - what if my function ends by an if statement? Like, if it's a countdown function and then if (minutes and seconds == "0"), then inside that there's some code that aborts/ends the function (i'm using speech recognition). Where could I put the setTimeout function?

Comment: @spin99, you should create a *new* question containing the *new* issue/question.

Comment: @Lain - hey just asked the new question if you wanted to check it out :)

Comment: @spin99 I have no experience with speech recognition sadly.